# Where to save files and install software in a full install usb

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb, files

I have a full install Ubuntu 14.04 on my pen drive. As far as I know,it's supposed to be a full install because I did it using a live dvd and moreover,there is no option to install from the usb pen drive,which was not the case for live or persistent pen drive,from which one is allowed to install Ubuntu. Now,when I boot from my usb drive,and get to the unity desktop,I wonder if there is anything similar to the 'My Computer' as in windows,from where I can view the available space,and save files,documents,images,songs etc. And how can I install softwares in Ubuntu?

Comment: So, Ubuntu was installed to the pen drive?  I don't really understand your actual question, so perhaps you can edit to make it more clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I used a live dvd to install ubuntu to my pen drive. Now,I was wondering where to access the drives to see free space,used space,to save files etc. as I do in 'my computer' in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not sure of your actual questions either.

This might help you to understand what you have done.

When you install an OS, files are added to a disk.
In Microsoft, this would be the C: drive.

Linux does not have drive letters to define the hardware.

Linux connects hardware to a directory.

Microsoft has created something called 'My Computer' which all disk drives appear to be connected to in Windows manager.

Linux has a file system that is made up of one or more disks connected together in one file system tree. The top of the file system is known as the root of the file system and is denoted as '/'.

I do not remember if Ubuntu 14 is a single install ISO or if there is a live desktop and live server version ISO. Ubuntu 15.x has 2 downloads, a desktop and a server version.

Assuming you copied the install ISO using the 'dd' command, what you did was essentially duplicate all the files that represent the installation (on the C: drive of a windows host, all the partitions on a Linux host) onto a single device (USB) drive, equivalent to the D: drive in a windows world.

You normally have to force the motherboard to boot off a USB device or it will default to using the local hard drive, the C: drive in windows.

If you were to boot this device by rebooting your host, it would bring up a Ubuntu console (server version) or a graphical desktop (desktop version).

If you try to view this USB stick on windows, you will get nothing. Windows does not have a driver that will view the format of this USB stick (ext4 is my guess). Hence you cannot see it from Windows.

If you boot this USB device on your host, you will bring up a console or desktop view.

On the desktop view, there should be a file manager icon or option in the menu that you can start. This will give you access to a memory resident file system.

Here is where it gets weird. The USB device is mounted as the underlying file system and memory is used for the disk space you save files to.

Put another USB device in, windows format or linux, and then copy your files to these devices.

Linux hosts can usually mount and use Windows formatted devices but not the other way around.

Hope this helps.